# Azure synapse, SQL pool as a source in dataflow

Tags: sql, azure, pool, dataflow, azure-synapse

I try to use Serverless Sql Pool Integration dataset in Azure Analitycs DataFlow as a source but I can't. SQL Pool is unavailable as a Source in DataFlow, but I don't know why?
[image]

What is a problem? I use SQL Pool datasets in Azure Synapse Pipelines and it works. Is it problem with my licence, version or maybe I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried selecting Synapse Dataset instead of SQL

You will need a Synapse Linked Service as well

[image]

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked :)